# Representing a diverged integration in term of non-elementary functions

Tags: calculus, integration

I know that the following integration diverges
$$
I = \int_0^\infty  {\frac{{\sqrt {{{(x + a)}^2} + {b^2}} }}{x}{e^{ - x}}dx},
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are constants. But are there any ways to represent the above integration in term of non-elementary functions such as Gamma function, Exponential Integral function, etc ?

Comment: The divergence does not have a connection with whether there is an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: No, it doesn't. However I don't think the above integration can be repsented just by elementary functions.